# Ruby Treetop how to include everything that does not match the grammar

Tags: ruby, parsing, treetop

I am tying to create a treetop grammar. I have created the rules to match sections in the file that are of interest to me.

```
grammar Sexp

  rule bodies
    body+
  end

  rule body
    commentPortString (ifdef_blocks / interface)+ (!newLine)
  end
...
end
```

How do I run this on a file to extract out the `bodies` and ignore other sections that I dont care about, or do I need to end up writing rules for those sections also?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common idiom in PEG grammars to repeatedly match any character `.` that isn't part of a rule `!body`. Something like this:

```
rule bodies
  ((!body .)* body)+ (!body .)*
end
```

Comment: Thanks works. But it slows down the parser significantly.

Comment: It might help performance-wise to do `((!commentPortString .)* body)+ (!commentPortString .)*` instead, or to not match spaces inside `commentPortString` (I mean move it outside the rule). Just some ideas.